# HTC Evo 3D Preview

Tags: android, htc-android

Im trying to get the preview from the separate backfacing cameras in HTC Evo 3D. I access the camera using camera.open(CAMERA_STEREOSCOPIC) but the preview aspect ratio is 640x480 or 1270x768. There are two camera images at the same image side by side.

Obviously some of the image information is lost, because each image is half the original size in x axis. I want to do some image processing so I need the full sized images. And also, taking pictures and then processing is not what i want to do.

Any ideas?

regards

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

" Note that we need to check the result of our call to DisplaySetting.setStereoscopic3DFormat in case the method fails for any reason. It will return true if it succeeded setting the format otherwise false.

If it should fail, you will be displaying a side be side LR image, which is probably not what you intended. In this case you may want to crop the L or R image out and scale the image to the appropriate size."

The info from HTC official website: http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/stereoscopic-3d/s3d-sample-code/
Maybe you should post the code and see what actually happens inside.