# HTC Evo 3D stereoscopic preview - reduced horizontal resolution

Tags: android, stereoscopy, htc-android

I'm writing an Android application which makes some use of stereoscopic image data from camera on HTC Evo 3D. I try to access the data using standard Android API with some 3D-specific functions provided by HTC OpenSense API. So far, I can access the camera in stereoscopic mode and I can grab the image data using `onPreviewFrame()` callback method.

However, the "raw" image data (`data[]` byte array) available in `onPreviewFrame()` are not complete. The image I get is a correct side-by-side stereoscopic picture, but its horizontal size is reduced by a factor of two. For example, when set the camera preview size to 1280x720 px, I expect a 2560x720 px image (two images of the desired 1280x720 px resolution). But what I get is a picture of 1280x720 resolution, half of which comes from the right camera and the other half from the left one. I don't know why is the horizontal resolution reduced.

There is [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347861/htc-evo-3d-preview) on this forum, but the answer doesn't really solve the problem. Although the `DisplaySetting.setStereoscopic3DFormat()` returns true in my program, it doesn't seem to have any effect on display or image data.

Has anyone any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution halving is by design, the parallax barrier display causes 3D photos to be half the resolution.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to access complete image data with original resolution?